# how to write NSDate in text file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm using [str writeToFile:path atomically encoding error]
to write in file. It works successfully for NSString but doesn't work for NSDate/NSData.
Please tell me how to write in file.

Comment: So `NSDate` or `NSData`?  They are very different classes.

Comment: What's your code? Did you read the `NSError` parameter? What's wrong exactly? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, cheater solution: put it inside a structure that does support writing to a file.

```
NSDate* variable = ...;
[@[ variable ] writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

That's to say, put it inside an array or dictionary.

If you want to output it to a *text* file (as you title suggests but you don't mention in the question), you need to convert the date into a string first. Use `NSDateFormatter`.

Without knowing what's inside your `NSData` it's not really possible to say how to output to a text file. Maybe convert to base 64 first?

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
My use case is that I have an object which contains array of object2 where object2 is made up of several attributes like NSInteger, NSArray, NSDate etc. How to write this object in file ?